# Visa approval date

Tags: canada, applications, nigerian-citizens

Hello admin I applied for Canada visa few months ago, am going for serious meeting in October 23. I was told to wait for an email for approval, I haven’t seen anything yet as at today... do I still have hope?

Comment: `few months` could be 2 or 5 or 11 months. What was the date to be exact?

Comment: Your question misses a lot of information, please [edit] it. Also: where did you apply?

Answer (score 1):

For applicants from Nigeria the [average processing time](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html) is 37 Days.[image]

That’s minus

> the the time it takes to send an application between a VAC and our
>   office and the time you need to give your biometrics

Nobody can tell you if you have *hope* or not however it’s almost time for your serious meeting. You will find out soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to consider if your application have really passed average processing times. If that is the case you are allowed to contact the visa office. If that is not the case the visa office may not respond to you. To check processing times please follow this URL
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html

If someone is waiting for you in Canada for the meeting. I suggest you ask your Canadian sponsor (The person who invited you for the meeting) to contact IRCC (You can only contact IRCC if you are in Canada. Thus only your sponsor may contact IRCC)

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/contact-ircc/client-support-centre.html

While that is happening. Try to contact the office that is processing your application using the web form

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/web-form.asp

There is no guarantee that your visa will be processed faster. Try to be very professional and make sure to write an appropriate letter to them with valid reason and as much as possible details about your meetings.

For more information on what cases are considered urgent please look at the following URL
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/canadian-citizenship/admininistration/general-file-processing/urgent-application-cases.html

It is clear to me that your case is not a valid urgent case but your application may be stuck at some stage and combination of an email and a phone call may lead to moving your application forward.